# MySQL indices and order

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

This is a question that I've had forever.

As far as I know the order of indices matter. So an index like `[first_name, last_name]` is not the same as `[last_name, first_name]`, right?

If I only define the first index, does it mean that it will only used for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name="john" AND  last_name="doe";
```

and not for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  last_name="doe" AND first_name="john";
```

Since I am using a ORM, I have no idea in which order these columns are going to be called. Does that mean that I have to add indices on all permutations? That is doable if I have a 2 column index, but what happens if my index is on 3 or 4 columns?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Index order matters when your query conditions only apply to **PART** of the index. Consider:

1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name="john" AND last_name="doe"`
2. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name="john"`
3. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_name="doe"`

If your index is (`first_name`, `last_name`) queries 1 and 2 will use it, query #3 won't.
If your index is (`last_name`, `first_name`) queries 1 and 3 will use it, query #2 won't. Changing the condition order within WHERE clause has no effect in either case.

Details are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

**Update**:
In case the above is not clear - MySQL can only use an index if the columns in query conditions form a leftmost prefix of the index. Query #2 above can not use (`last_name`, `first_name`) index because it's only based on `first_name` and `first_name` is NOT the leftmost prefix of the (`last_name`, `first_name`) index.

The order of conditions WITHIN the query does not matter; query #1 above will be able to use  (`last_name`, `first_name`) index just fine because its conditions are  `first_name` and `last_name` and, taken together, they DO form a leftmost prefix of (`last_name`, `first_name`) index.

Comment: So I guess SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_name="doe" AND first_name="john" won't? 

If that's the case, then since all the query building is hidden by my ORM, I probably have to define the 2 indices... which really sucks, because I have an index on 3 columns to define...

Comment: No, you've misunderstood. WHERE `last_name`="doe" AND `first_name`="john" query would use either (`first_name`, `last_name`) or (`last_name`, `first_name`) indexes just fine.

Comment: Great summary for a common question

Comment: `WHERE last_name = 'doe' and first_name LIKE 'j%'` -- in _this_ case, `INDEX(last_name, first_name)` is better than the other options.  That is because of the "range" on `first_name`.  [_Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)

Comment: what if i have index (`first_name`, `last_name`, `full_name`) and query: where `first_name like"doe" and full_name like "john_doe"` does this use index

Answer (score 5):

ChssPly76 is correct that the order of boolean expressions does not have to match the order of columns in the index.  Boolean operators are [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity), and the MySQL optimizer is smart enough to know how to match the expression to the index in most cases.

I also want to add that you should learn how to use the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) feature of MySQL so you can see for yourself which indexes the optimizer will choose for a given query.

Comment: MySQL Workbench shows a graphical representation of the `EXPLAIN` information under `Execution Plan`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to extend the answer a little bit to make completely everything crystal clear at once.

If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, you have indexed search capabilities on `(col1)`, `(col1, col2)`, and `(col1, col2, col3)`.

MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statements shown here:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
```

If an index exists on `(col1, col2, col3)`, only the first two queries use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed columns, but `(col2)` and `(col2, col3)` are not leftmost prefixes of `(col1, col2, col3)`. - [MySQL dev](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col3=val3; are this query using index too?