# Effects of order of columns, while defining an index on them, on the performance of the queries

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

Does order of the columns in an Index definition for a table in a database has any effect on the performance?
for e.g. are these two queries different ?
CREATE INDEX xxx ON tablex(col1,col2)
CREATE INDEX xxx ON tablex(col2,col1)

what about the in case that I use a BTREE index?
I am using Mysql.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL indices and order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252279/mysql-indices-and-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does make a difference. An index on (col1, col2) can serve queries that only require an index on col1 but it cannot be used for queries that require only col2.

Comment: +1, this isn't limited to MySQL by the way, many DBMS' follow this behaviour.