# Will indexes on my MySQL tables improve my website performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two very simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_words` (
  `fld_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fld_word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_id`)
);
```

This holds a long list of words, with about 10,500 words listed in it. Each word also has a CatID in it, which corresponds to a word category in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `j_word_cat` (
  `fld_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fld_cat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_id`)
);
```

The pages that take data from these tables get about 500,000 page views a month. The data in the tables is pretty static and is rarely, if ever, updated.

I'm finding that the MySQL database I'm using is returning quite a few of these errors a day:

Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I wondered - would performance be improved if I added a new index to the "tbl_words" table, e.g., an Index called "catID", and linked to the "fld_cat_id" column.

Or should I create an index which uses both e.g. fld_id AND fld_cat_id together?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

## UPDATE

My queries are pretty simple - I don't actually join the tables.

The user selects a category from the j_word_cat table, and then that ID is used to generate a random list of words, e.g these are some common queries I'm running:

```
-- Category table to populate SELECT drop down list of categories:
SELECT fld_cat, fld_id FROM j_word_cat ORDER BY fld_cat;

-- common word table selects:
-- the NOT IN bit is to exclude one category which I want to exclude by default unless the user actually chooses it
SELECT fld_word FROM tbl_words WHERE fld_cat_id NOT IN (24) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;

-- note that the value of 15 would vary depending on the category the user selected
-- 15 is just an example

SELECT fld_word FROM tbl_words WHERE fld_cat_id = 15 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;

SELECT fld_word FROM tbl_words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 60;
```

Comment: What queries are you running against these tables?  That info is need to determine the optimal indexes needed.

Comment: the short answer is YES! but also post your queries they may need to be optimized as well!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies - I have posted some of the most commonly used queries

Answer (score 0):

According to your queries, you need the following indexes

```
j_word_cat(fld_cat) # because you are sorting by this field
tbl_words(fld_cat_id) # because you are filtering by this field
```

Since you are not joining the tables and you are not filtering by different columns, you should not create composites indexes that you do not need.

I am going to recommend you to read [this article](http://odetocode.com/Articles/70.aspx) that helped me a lot. Note: it is a bit old and speaks about SQL server but it is very useful to understand SQL indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will speed up selects and slow down inserts and updates, however I often deal with tables with several million records and we can reduce the speed of a query from 4 to 5 minutes to less than 1 second with proper indexes, where the impact on insert and update is negligible.

If you create some indexes and wonder if they are used then you can look at your query using mysql Explain tool

```
EXPLAIN SELECT fld_word 
FROM tbl_words WHERE fld_cat_id NOT IN (24) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

In your result you will see a list of possible indexes and the index ultimately selected. Pay special attention to the "rows" column as this will show how many rows it had to scan for each table in the result.

Ultimately you want to strive for zero unindexed queries to be running on your server and the queries that are run should scan as few rows as possible.. My suggestion is to turn on the unindexed query log in your mysql.ini file and fix all the queries where it is reasonable to do so.

if you join or order by or use where it will improve performance, if you just select unordered information without joining then it will not.

fld_cat_id should be indexed

Your primary keys should be declared as such. If you want to fully optimize them then make them not null, unsigned, auto_increment and assign them to be the primary key.

if you are doing something like where fld_word = 'bla' then that should be indexed along with any join keys used.

If you have a small database then the performance increase is negligible, however that is no reason to be lazy about good design.

More reading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252288/243439
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html